# Why is the JVM memory footprint smaller than -Xms?

Tags: java, linux, jvm, heap-memory

The startup command for the application is as follows:

```
java -server -Xms15g -Xmx15g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=77 -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

The following information can be obtained from the JVM command of arthas:

```
 RUNTIME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MACHINE-NAME                                   7@authserver-5fc5c7c775-9fs2m
 JVM-START-TIME                                 2020-04-15 00:04:27
 MANAGEMENT-SPEC-VERSION                        1.2
 SPEC-NAME                                      Java Virtual Machine Specification
 SPEC-VENDOR                                    Oracle Corporation
 SPEC-VERSION                                   1.8
 VM-NAME                                        Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 VM-VENDOR                                      Oracle Corporation
 VM-VERSION                                     25.111-b14
 INPUT-ARGUMENTS                                -javaagent:/var/agent/pinpoint-agent/pinpoint-bootstrap.jar
                                                -Xms15g
                                                -Xmx15g
                                                -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
                                                -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
                                                -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
                                                -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=77
                                                -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
                                                -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
                                                -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

 CLASS-PATH                                     /app.jar:/var/agent/pinpoint-agent/pinpoint-bootstrap.jar
 BOOT-CLASS-PATH                                /usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/sunrsasign.jar
                                                :/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/charsets.jar:/usr
                                                /java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_111/classes
 LIBRARY-PATH                                   /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CLASS-LOADING
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 LOADED-CLASS-COUNT                             21926
 TOTAL-LOADED-CLASS-COUNT                       21944
 UNLOADED-CLASS-COUNT                           18
 IS-VERBOSE                                     false

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 COMPILATION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NAME                                           HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
 TOTAL-COMPILE-TIME                             366850(ms)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GARBAGE-COLLECTORS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ParNew                                         1797/78247(ms)
 [count/time]
 ConcurrentMarkSweep                            3/460(ms)
 [count/time]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MEMORY-MANAGERS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CodeCacheManager                               Code Cache

 Metaspace Manager                              Metaspace
                                                Compressed Class Space

 ParNew                                         Par Eden Space
                                                Par Survivor Space

 ConcurrentMarkSweep                            Par Eden Space
                                                Par Survivor Space
                                                CMS Old Gen


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MEMORY
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HEAP-MEMORY-USAGE                              15992750080(14.9 GiB)/16106127360(15.0 GiB)/15992750080(14.9 GiB)/2393542120(2.2 GiB)
 [committed/init/max/used]
 NO-HEAP-MEMORY-USAGE                           255647744(243.8 MiB)/2555904(2.4 MiB)/-1(-1 B)/247922192(236.4 MiB)
 [committed/init/max/used]
 PENDING-FINALIZE-COUNT                         0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OPERATING-SYSTEM
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 OS                                             Linux
 ARCH                                           amd64
 PROCESSORS-COUNT                               16
 LOAD-AVERAGE                                   5.08
 VERSION                                        4.4.0-141-generic

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 THREAD
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 COUNT                                          256
 DAEMON-COUNT                                   103
 PEAK-COUNT                                     263
 STARTED-COUNT                                  41467
 DEADLOCK-COUNT                                 0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 FILE-DESCRIPTOR
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MAX-FILE-DESCRIPTOR-COUNT                      1048576
 OPEN-FILE-DESCRIPTOR-COUNT                     811
Affect(row-cnt:0) cost in 6 ms.
```

From the above information, you can see that both committed/init of the JVM heap are about 15GiB.

However, from the system top command or the free command, the memory footprint of this process is only 3.712g

**the result of the top command is shown**
[image]

**the result of the free command is shown**
[image]

Comment: What do you think the other 25.25g in VIRT is?

Comment: Try to start with `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`.